# Six degrees of Kevin Bacon in Perl

Tags: perl, data-structures, graph-theory, graph-traversal

First yes, this is a homework project for my Perl class.  I am not looking for the answer (although that would be sweet).  As I understand it I need to use a BFS and a regular expression to organize my data for use.  I need some direction on this one.  How do I use a BFS?  Do I use a massive stack and go through each item in the stack?  Should I use a giant hash table?  Has anyone worked on this problem?  How did you go about doing it?  I just need some direction is all.  Is this similar to a BST?  Is this possible without using the graph module?  Is this possible using hash values?

Comment: ... and why do you have to use an 'ugly regular expression' ? Can't you use a beautiful one?

Comment: You might really like Mastering Algorithms with Perl from OReily. http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565923980

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't an *answer*, but it's hints towards your answer.

You are best served by first looking up what a Breadth First Search is in a graph.

Also, if you have not been given a regular expression, you may consider the *tokenizing* problem and look that up. Possibly that won't be needed. Check the assignment and see if you can just *slurp* in some information.

Answer (score 6):

See [Graph](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Graph/).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use autodie;
use strict; use warnings;

use Graph;
use Graph::TransitiveClosure::Matrix;

my $dat = 'kevin-bacon.dat';

my $kbg = Graph->new(undirected => 1);

open my $kbf, '<', $dat;

my %movies;

while ( my $line = <$kbf> ) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    chomp $line;
    my ($u, $m, $v) = split /;/, $line;
    $kbg->add_edge($u, $v);
    $movies{"$u|$v"} = $movies{"$v|$u"} = $m;
}

my $tcm = Graph::TransitiveClosure::Matrix->new($kbg,
    path_length => 1,
    path_vertices => 1,
);

my ($u, $v) = ('Kevin Bacon', 'Yelena Maksimova');

if ( my $n = $tcm->path_length($u, $v) ) {
    printf "%d degrees of separation between %s and %s\n", $n, $u, $v;
}

my @path = $tcm->path_vertices($u, $v);

for my $i ( 0 .. @path - 2 ) {
    my ($u, $v) = @path[$i, $i + 1];
    print qq{$u - $v: $movies{"$u|$v"}\n};
}
```

Using `kevin-bacon.dat` from the Boost project:

```
3 degrees of separation between Kevin Bacon and Yelena Maksimova
Kevin Bacon - Elisabeth Shue: Hollow Man (2000)
Elisabeth Shue - Lev Prygunov: Saint, The (1997)
Lev Prygunov - Yelena Maksimova: Bezottsovshchina (1976)
```